# Many of who or many of whom?

Tags: word-choice

In the sentence "The convention was attended by hundreds of executives, many of *who/whom* stopped by our stand to.." should it be "many of who" or "many of whom"?

Comment: The linked question does not ask about this specific case, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Actually @Jake, I think the most upvoted answer definitely does apply, especially if you substitute they/them (since "many" can't refer to singular he/him) for who/whom. One of the comments on that answer suggests exactly this, although that may have been motivated more by maintaining gender neutrality....

Answer (score 0):

*Many of whom* for formal contexts, *many of who* for informal ones.

Comment: How can the formality make a difference?  It's either correct or it isn't.

Comment: -1. I agree with @Jake. This is a poor-quality answer without any supporting evidence or even an explanation.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica an answer written in 2013 but in its simplicity it's perfectly correct. Now someone might argue that only "whom" is correct but "who" is precisely "informal".